# Cartesian Product for Group members

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 or more Groups like below in a table:

```
Id  Value GroupId
1   A       1
2   B       1
3   C       2
4   D       2
```

Now I wanna show total relationships (total: 2*2=4 since we have 2 groups each one with 2 members) like below:

```
A & C 
A & D
B & C
B & D
```

Or with three Groups:

```
Id  Value GroupId
1   A       1
2   B       1
3   C       2
4   D       2
5   E       3
6   F       3
```

We have 2*2*2=8 relationships:

```
A & C & E
A & D & E
B & C & E
B & D & E
A & C & F
A & D & F
B & C & F
B & D & F
```

But, how can I do this via **Linq Expression**? I want the result to show in View(razor).

**Update:**
My meaning is [Cartesian Product](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Cartesian_product.html) of Group members in the Table.

Comment: It's not clear what you're using "state" to mean here... do you mean selecting one entry from each group? Where is this data coming from? (It may be tricky to do in LINQ to SQL, but relatively straightforward in LINQ to Objects.

Comment: @JonSkeet State means total relationships among members based on their groups. Yes selecting one entry from each group to show with ather group members each time with separate members of each group. Data Comming from Database

Comment: I strongly suggest you give an example with three groups. Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated question with an example with 3 group members. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the groups into `groups`. move the first group into `result`. Then for each remaining `group`, join them with `result` :

```
        IEnumerable<string> result;

        var groups = (from item in list
                      group item by item.GroupId into grp
                      select grp.Select(t => t.Value)).ToList();

        result = groups.First();

        groups.RemoveAt(0);

        groups.ForEach(delegate(IEnumerable<string> value)
            {
                result = (from r in result
                         from v in value
                         select r + " " + v).ToList();

            });
```

Comment: I tested yours.It doesn't make sense. Are you sure of its true logic/syntax?

Comment: I thought you only wanted the count. I will try and edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but it seems to me as a filtered cartesian product of elements from different group. And if so, this code could help:

```
var result = elements.SelectMany(x => elements, 
                                (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y))
                     .Where(t => t.Item1.GroupId < t.Item2.GroupId)
                     .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Item1.Value, t.Item2.Value))
                     .ToList();
```

*Note*: this creates some temporary objects so be aware when using with very big collections.

Comment: How is that going to work for more than two groups? I think the OP wants tuples of three values if there are three groups, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet, true, we do not know that, I understand this in that way. Let's wait for the OP clarification...

Comment: The OP has now clarified it.

Comment: Thanks. Your code worked fine for 2 groups when i employed the necessary condition to avoid generation of the same `Tuple`s like (a,b)=(b,a). But How to figure out the solution when I don't know how many sets(groups) exist?