# N-Ary/Multiple-List Cartesian Product

Tags: linq, cartesian

in Product SKUs, 
we can get Cartesian Product in the way of LINQ:

```
string[] arr1 = new[] {"red", "blue", "orange"};
string[] arr2 = new[] {"5 inche", "8 inch"};
var result = from a in arr1
             from b in arr2
             select a + " " + b;
foreach (var item in result){
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

We know the exact number of arrays.

My question is: If the number of arrays is dynamic, how do we get Cartesian Product?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more precise - you have `arr1` & `arr2` and then you talk about `array`. Which are you referring to? Both? Or are you saying if you have multiple arrays and not just two?

Comment: @Raeen Hashemi, thanks,your clue solved my problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I am saying multiple arrays.Thanks too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put them in a `list` of string arrays. Then I'd use `ForEach`:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = list.First();

list.RemoveAt(0);

list.ForEach(delegate(IEnumerable<string> value)
{
     result = (from r in result
               from v in value
               select r + " " + v).ToList();

});
```

You can also see this link : [Cartesian Product for Group members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578473/cartesian-product-for-group-members/26586955#26586955)

Comment: @Enigmativity If we have many arrays and we don't know the count of them, the only way I can think of is a ForEach on the list and every time, we use that Linq on every array and the previous results we got from the previous arrays. See the link for another example.

Comment: Very clever. I generally try to avoid state and use recursion instead for these kinds of things. Interesting approach.

Answer (score 3):

I liked Raeen's answer and it made me think of a simple linq way to solve this problem. This is a very similar method, but doesn't involve any state external to the computation.

```
var list = new List<IEnumerable<string>>()
{
    new[] {"red", "blue", "orange"},
    new[] {"5 inche", "8 inch"},
    new[] {"x", "y"},
};

var result =
    list
        .Aggregate((rs, vs) =>
            from r in rs
            from v in vs
            select r + " " + v)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: +1. I think this is *a lot* prettier than the accepted answer due to no mutable state outside of `Aggregate`. May I suggest adding `list.DefaultIfEmpty(Enumerable.Empty<string>())` before the call to `Aggregate` so as to avoid the `InvalidOperationException` if `list.Count` is zero?